# Need help to create a second level sub-folder

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I have the following code which creates a sub-folder in a desktop directory. This works fine, no problem.

However, I would like to create another sub-folder within the newly created sub-folder. The code I am using at the moment is:

```
Dim ab = New DirectoryInfo(Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop), "Client\" & TextBox1.Text))
            If Not ab.Exists Then ab.Create()

            ‘Need help here on how to create another sub-folder within the newly created sub-folder…
Dim fi = New DirectoryInfo(?????)
            If Not fi.Exists Then fi.Create()
```

Please how do I get the program to do this?

Comment: How about `fi = New DirectoryInfo(Path.Combine(ab.FullName, "subdirectory"));`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Save the original folder location in a string variable, and then you can build on it as needed.

```
StartPath = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop), _ 
         "Client\" & TextBox1.Text)

Dim ab = New DirectoryInfo(StartPath)
If Not ab.Exists Then ab.Create()

StartPath = Path.Combine(StartPath, "NextLevel\")

Dim fi = New DirectoryInfo(StartPath)
If Not fi.Exists Then fi.Create()
```

Comment: _ Many thanks for taking the time to share your knowledge. I am most grateful.

Answer (score 0):

Keep the adress of the first folder you create in a string, and just use it as a base to the subfolders.

Comment: See ken white's answer for code example (writing from a cellphone it's very hard to properly give code examples)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a very simple way to create an entire path:

```
Dim ensureExists As Action(Of DirectoryInfo) = Nothing
ensureExists = Sub(di)
    di.Refresh()
    If Not di.Exists
        ensureExists(di.Parent)
        di.Create()
    End If
End Sub
```

Now you just call `ensureExists` with a `DirectoryInfo` of the full path that you want and it just makes sure the whole thing is there.

```
ensureExists(New DirectoryInfo(Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop), "Client\" & TextBox1.Text)))
```